# Java Bean - Need same object via prototype scope

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hashmap

For thread safety issue occurred, we are converting our singleton beans as prototype. But in one scenario we still need same object (with in that thread) for multiple map item. But prototype is giving different object (of course it will). I'm not sure how to achieve it.

For e.g. in below bean A, B1 and B2 are referred twice (which are prototye beans). New B1 and B2 object is getting created each time with in same thread. I want only one B1 and B2 object in the same thread even though I referenced it twice. If B1 and B2 is singleton it will be same across al thread which should not be happening. Could you please provide some idea on how to achieve it.

```
<bean id="A" class="mypackage.foo" scope="prototype">
 <property name="myMap">
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean">
     <property name="targetMapClass">
       <value>java.util.HashMap</value>
     </property>
     <property name="sourceMap">
     <map>
      <entry key="KEY1">
        <ref bean="B1"></ref>
      </entry>
      <entry key="KEY2">
        <ref bean="B2"></ref>
      </entry>
      <entry key="KEY3">
        <ref bean="B1"></ref>
      </entry>
      <entry key="KEY4">
        <ref bean="B2"></ref>
      </entry>
     </map>
   </property>
  </bean>
</property>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are developing a web application, you may consider using request scope if you handle a http request in a single thread. If not, you may want to register the [SimpleThreadScope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/SimpleThreadScope.html) and use that to declare your beans.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. i added custom bean for simplethread scope and used that. Thanks alot

Comment: Just be sure to nicely clean up your threadscope. If the threads are reused you might run into "old" data.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the advice. I will double check.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Apokralipsa suugestion, added below bean and then used the thread as scope  which solved the issue.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
      <property name="scopes">
          <map>
              <entry key="thread">
                  <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope"/>
              </entry>
          </map>
      </property>
  </bean>
```